# What should I consider when bumping a version of a single openembedded-core recipe while keeping the rest of poky at an earlier version?

Tags: yocto, openembedded

I'm working with a board where the manufacturer-provided BSP and SDK is meant to work with Yocto Project 3.0 (`zeus`). However I'd like to use a fresher version of Python 3 than the one baked into the `zeus` branch of Yocto.

Would simply copying a fresher Python 3 recipe from a recent `openembedded-core` be sufficient to do that or do I risk running into trouble that won't show as bake-time errors?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I tried this before when I was working on **sumo** branch which is so old and I used python3 from **zeus** branch and it was so painful because python3 recipes have a lot of patches, but finally I did it.

It is basically the same recipe with another version and other patches, you have to focus on not missing any patch or messing up the recipe content.

Best Regards,
Talel